# Run a shellscript N times

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, unix, aix

I am trying to run a shellscript N times by writing the following code in another shell script for example **loopRun.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..20}
do
exec sampleShellscript.sh;
sleep 10
done
```

Executing the shellscript as follows

```
sh -x loopRun.sh
```

The inner shellscript runs for about 30seconds and it exits without looping

Please suggest on what can be done to achieve the desired result

Comment: This might help: `help exec`

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec` command replaces the current shell process with the program being executed. Don't use it if you need the current script to continue after the program is done.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..20}
do
    sampleShellscript.sh;
    sleep 10
done
```

Since `{1..20}` is a bash extension, you can't run the script with `sh`. Use

```
bash -x loopRun.sh
```